# Accidental unprotection (then reprotection) of a question

Tags: support, specific-question

I guess I recently acquired the [protect questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) privilege. In my tired state of reading a question that I thought was good, I thought it was a [locked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post). Believing it to be good, I went to vote for reopening. In my haste, I accidentally (I believe) "unprotected" the question flat out with my new privilege. I realized my mistake and quickly protected it again, but I don't know if that was the right action to take. I have read a few other posts and understand a bit more about when to use the feature now, and I can see why the question was originally in that state.

Is there a rollback to the original state, or something else to do here?

(post where this occurred: [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl))

Comment: haven't you already essentially rolled it back to the original state?

Comment: (Honestly - this question doesn't seem to rise to the need of protection.  There aren't enough answers by super new people to justify this.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. So, maybe there is nothing else to do here. I just wanted to reach out as I didn't see other questions with a similar description. The original protection banner was done at some point by somebody, so I don't know if that is important.

Comment: @Makoto: there are at least 3 deleted answers & a lot of answers already. Protecting it / leaving it protected doesn't shock me.

Comment: @Jean: The deleted answers would've been able to have been posted even with the protection. There's no reason to have it.

Comment: you're right! didn't check rep of answerers. I'm not going to unprotect that one anyway

Comment: @Makoto: But it was presumably protected for a long time before now.  Who knows how many more low-quality answers it would have attracted had it been unprotected the whole time.  Perhaps a lot, if it even managed to attract a few low-quality answers from users who *were* allowed to post them.  I tend to protect questions after one crappy answer, especially if it's a basic newbie question that already has a good answer (or good enough in the case of low quality questions), or if it has multiple good answers.

Comment: The specific question in this case has 884k views, and would be a prime candidate for questions posted as answers when people try the command in the top answer but it doesn't work for them (because of whatever misconfiguration, or not having OpenSSL installed, or whatever.  Or for questions about doing something with the cert.)

Comment: @Makoto: Since protection requires only 10 rep to overcome I protect questions when I'm deleting spam off them (SOCVR is really fast for deleting spam) more than once.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've already done it - the original protection banner is lost forever, but the question is now protected by you instead.